# Почему Laravel5 ругается на функцию preg_replace_callback() и не загружает страницы?

Tags: php, laravel

laravel5 после установки, при загрузке страницы home выдает такую ошибку:

```
ErrorException in compiled.php line 13841: preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: internal error: previously-checked referenced subpattern not found at offset 47
    in compiled.php line 13841
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: internal error: previously-checked referenced subpattern not found at offset 47', '/var/www/laravel/vendor/compiled.php', '13841', array('value' => '@extends('app') @section('content') <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> <div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="panel-heading">Login</div> <div class="panel-body"> @if (count($errors) > 0) <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br> <ul> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach </ul> </div> @endif <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}"> <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me </label> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button> <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a> </div> </div> </form> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> @endsection ', 'callback' => object(Closure)))
    at preg_replace_callback('/\B@(\w+)([ \t]*)(\( ( (?>[^()]+) | (?3) )* \))?/x', object(Closure), '@extends('app') @section('content') <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> <div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="panel-heading">Login</div> <div class="panel-body"> @if (count($errors) > 0) <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br> <ul> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach </ul> </div> @endif <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}"> <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me </label> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button> <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a> </div> </div> </form> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> @endsection ') in compiled.php line 13841
    at BladeCompiler->compileStatements('@extends('app') @section('content') <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> <div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="panel-heading">Login</div> <div class="panel-body"> @if (count($errors) > 0) <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br> <ul> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach </ul> </div> @endif <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}"> <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me </label> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button> <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a> </div> </div> </form> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> @endsection ') in compiled.php line 13784
    at BladeCompiler->parseToken(array('314', '@extends('app') @section('content') <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> <div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="panel-heading">Login</div> <div class="panel-body"> @if (count($errors) > 0) <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br> <ul> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach </ul> </div> @endif <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}"> <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me </label> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button> <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a> </div> </div> </form> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> @endsection ', '1')) in compiled.php line 13772
    at BladeCompiler->compileString('@extends('app') @section('content') <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> <div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="panel-heading">Login</div> <div class="panel-body"> @if (count($errors) > 0) <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br> <ul> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach </ul> </div> @endif <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}"> <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label> <div class="col-md-6"> <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me </label> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button> <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a> </div> </div> </form> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> @endsection ') in compiled.php line 13755
    at BladeCompiler->compile('/var/www/laravel/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php') in compiled.php line 13680
    at CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/laravel/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in compiled.php line 13523
    at View->getContents() in compiled.php line 13510
    at View->renderContents() in compiled.php line 13501
    at View->render() in compiled.php line 14597
    at Response->setContent(object(View)) in compiled.php line 14126
    at Response->__construct(object(View)) in compiled.php line 7154
    at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in compiled.php line 6954
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8952
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8935
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 6955
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 6944
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 6929
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 1935
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8952
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2438
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8944
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12083
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8944
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 10785
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8944
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 11789
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8944
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 11738
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8944
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2478
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8944
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8935
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 1891
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 1880
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

PHP 5.6.9-1~dotdeb+7.1
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

На версии php 5.4 на другой системе все работает. Подскажите пожалуйста с чем может быть связанно!?

Comment: Скорее всего, сломался Blade и вам вам нужно в поддержку. Предоставьте эту строчку из `compiled.php` +- 20 строк.

Comment: Киньте ссылку пожалуйста, что за поддержка!?

Comment: Господи фреймворка.

Comment: Да понятно, что не телефонной компании! Куда с вопросом обращаться? На laravel.com нашел только форум. А по вашим словам, я так подозреваю есть специализированная служба в которой можно открыть тикет.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8567

Comment: Это я уже читал, там к сожалению решения так же нет.

Comment: Это и есть служба поддержки. Я не обещал вам никакого решения. Там рассматривается ровно ваш кейс.

Comment: Я понимаю! В системе на которой фреймворк работает версия библиотеки pcre 8.30, а на которой не работает 8.36. Видимо проблема в этом. Есть какое-то быстрое решение, что-бы откатить библиотеку до нужной версии или надо пересобрать php?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Этот вопрос следует спрашивать там.